# Execute SQL Server stored procedure from a batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a SQL Server stored procedure from a batch file. At the moment, it works fine on my pc (using localhost) but I need to use it in another PC, my stored procedure uses queries with linked server and when I trying to execute my batch file I get these messages:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

Maybe I need to send also my user and password in my batch file? Currently this is what I have in my .bat:

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec SP @Param= 1" -SServerIP -dDATABASE -o PATHTOMYTXTINFOFILE
```

Comment: Are you connecting using Windows Authentication?

Comment: @Jason Yes! But I don't want that everybody can see the user and the password from the batch file, I'm trying to create another user.

Comment: Instead of the Server IP for the -S parameter, try `-S ServerName\InstanceName`. You shouldn't have to put in a username and password unless you are connecting with SQL authentication

Comment: Are you sure a .bat file is the right thing? If you want to perform some task every day/hour or so, then couldn't you add it as a sql-server job? On server level under `SQL Server Agent > Jobs`.